# Magento 2, how to add 'textbox' into 'cancel modal'?

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, modal-popup

Using `magento 2.2`, `admin`. I need to add **textbox** into dialog when confirm **Cancel** status in sale order.

[image]

Comment: You need to change the UI component js and template and your input field.

Comment: Can you give me more detail? @MilindSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create module for override js file 
`\app\code\Magento\custombackend\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_custombackend" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`\app\code\Magento\custombackend\view\adminhtml\requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Sales/order/view/post-wrapper': 'Magento_custombackend/js/order/view/post-wrapper'
        }
    }
};
```

`\app\code\Magento\custombackend\view\adminhtml\web\js\order\view\post-wrapper.js`

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, confirm) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @param {String} url
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    function getForm(url) {
        return $('<form>', {
            'action': url,
            'method': 'POST'
        }).append($('<input>', {
            'name': 'form_key',
            'value': window.FORM_KEY,
            'type': 'hidden'
        }));
    }

    $('#order-view-cancel-button').click(function () {
        var msg = $.mage.__('Are you sure you want to cancel this order? <input type="text">'),
            url = $('#order-view-cancel-button').data('url');
        confirm({
            'content': msg,
            'actions': {

                /**
                 * 'Confirm' action handler.
                 */
                confirm: function () {
                    getForm(url).appendTo('body').submit();
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $('#order-view-hold-button').click(function () {
        var url = $('#order-view-hold-button').data('url');

        getForm(url).appendTo('body').submit();
    });

    $('#order-view-unhold-button').click(function () {
        var url = $('#order-view-unhold-button').data('url');

        getForm(url).appendTo('body').submit();
    });
});
```

`\app\code\Magento\custombackend\registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,    
'Magento_custombackend',    __DIR__);
?>
```

In magento 2.2.5 this dialog text come from this path
`\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\web\order\view\post-wrapper.js`

line :  29

```
var msg = $.mage.__('Are you sure you want to cancel this order? <input type="text">')
```

add textbox like this

[image]

Comment: How to override this file, coz Magento not allow to change file in _vendor_.?

Comment: check updated answer.. deal with create new module for override js file

Comment: do you have any idea how to get this post value